# Solving A Difficult Equation: $89 - (e^{\frac{m}{rd}}) = 64 - (e(\frac{m}{rd}))$. Why are they both equal?

Tags: eulers-number-e

I came across this weird formula when I was doing some machine learning stuff. The formula is

$$89 - (e^{\frac{m}{rd}}) = 64 - e(\frac{m}{rd})$$

They seem to be both equal, but I am just curious as to why. Please help. The variables are just there for placement, assuming that $m == m$, $r == r$, $d == d$. $e$ is Euler's constant. Thank you and appreciate your time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.